# How to create dynamic fixtures for ember integration tests using ember-testing (Qunit) via teabag

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

- I have setup the rather awesome **teabag**
  https://github.com/modeset/teabag to run integration tests on my
  ember app.
- I am following the process that Erik Bryn discussed in his
  presentation: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nO1hxT9GBTs using the
  code in https://github.com/ebryn/bloggr-client-rails as a template.
- I switch to the ember fixture adapter for testing.

I have everything working nicely with a static fixture which I define in a fixtures files like this:

```
var user = {
    id: 1,
    email: "test@testing.com",
    firstName: "Han",
    lastName: "Solo"
};
var userArray = [];
userArray.push(user);
App.User.FIXTURES = userArray;
```

But.... if I want to pull the fixture data in dynamically from my existing Rails seed data. (I rename the file to user_fixture.js.erb) and then do:

```
<% @user = User.find_by_email('test@testing.com') %>
var currentUser = <%= UserSerializer.new(@user, :root => false).to_json %>; 
var userArray = [];
userArray.push(user);
App.User.FIXTURES = userArray;
```

My tests fail. I can see that the data is not populating the ember app, but if I do:

```
App.User.Fixtures
```

from the console then I can see that the object exists as expected. I am out of ideas as to why this is the case, anyone have any suggestions?

For completeness here is how I am setting up Ember in the tests (The same as Erik Bryn's examples):

```
module("Home Routes:", {
  setup: function() {
    Ember.run(App, App.advanceReadiness);
  },
  teardown: function() {
    App.reset();
  }
});
```

and here is the contents of test_helper.js:

```
//= require application
//= require_tree .
//= require_self

document.write('<div id="ember-testing-container"><div id="ember-testing"></div></div>');
document.write('<style>#ember-testing-container { position: absolute; background: white; bottom: 45px; left: 45px; width: 640px; height: 384px; overflow: auto; z-index: 9999; border: 1px solid #ccc; } #ember-testing { zoom: 50%; }</style>');

App.rootElement = '#ember-testing';
App.setupForTesting();
App.injectTestHelpers();

function exists(selector) {
    return !!find(selector).length;
};
```

Update:
I have figured out that one (fingers crossed the only) problem with this is that the Active Model Serializer is creating underscore key names, and Ember is expecting camelized versions.

Comment: Just to clarify your first example -you would do this static fixture work in each test or in your setup fixture? if so how are you tearing it down to cleanup the fixture data. Also are you using ember-model or ember-data?

Comment: Hey Toran. I'm using ember-data, I'll add the test_helper and test code which is responsible for setting everything up. As I said before, everything works perfectly with a static fixture...

Comment: Right -just curious what a few of the missing details looked like for my own sake :)

Comment: Is there a way to get the CSS working correctly for the application with the setup code you've shown above? I just have the ugly white screen. Not sure how to reference the CSS of my rails app.

Comment: Hey Brandon. I'm using teabag which allows you to set the assets for your test suite. Including css obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after a bit of messing about I got it working. As I mentioned in my update above, the problem was that ember is expecting camelised attributes and Active Model Serializers creates dasherized ones.

```
module MyUtilities
  class Base

    # Convert keys from ruby object to camelized strings. e.g: :hello_there_world becomes "helloThereWorld"
    def self.camelize_keys(object)
      r = {}
      object.to_hash.each do |k,v|
        r[k.to_s.camelize(:lower)] = v
      end
      r
    end

  end
end


<% 
  user = User.find_by_email('test@testing.com') 
  user_hash = UserSerializer.new(user, :root => false).as_json
  @user = MyUtilities::Base.camelize_keys(user_hash).to_json
%>
var user = <%= @user %>; 
App.User.FIXTURES = [user];
```